# Magento 2 - How to get newsletter subscribers email id in transactional email templates without @domain.com

Tags: magento2.4.1, magento-2-commerce

I am using the following script to add in my email template,

```
Hi {{var subscriber.getSubscriberEmail()}}
```

Eg: **Hi abc123@gmail.com**

I want to name only, how to remove **@domain.com**

I need:  Hi **abc123**

Comment: you have to do the customization for this one by first remove the extra string before variable set.

Comment: Can u pls guide me on this, i tried but i am facing an error.